# Clearing all Textboxes in Multiple forms from a public module

Tags: .net, vb.net, textbox, refactoring, controls

Im a newbie in vb.net and actually adding my first question here, 
hope my question is not too lame.

I have 12 forms in my project.
I have created a 'public' module with procedures and functions to be used all over the forms.

With one of the procedures I intend to clear all Text boxes in a form - any form i'm in. 
this is the Procedure (suggested somewhere here....):

```
Public Sub ClearTextBoxes()
    Dim MyControl As Control
    For Each MyControl In controls
        If TypeOf MyControl Is TextBox Then
            MyControl.Text = ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I would like to call it from any form, with the form Name so it will clear all the text boxes in that active Form.

I guess i should call the procedure with a variable (like me.name) and add a ByVal in the procedure itself - but couldn't accomplish that yet

Awaiting a response
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
 Public Sub CLEAR_TEXTBOXES(ByVal frm As Form)
        For Each txtctrl In frm.Controls.OfType(Of Windows.Forms.TextBox)()
            txtctrl.Clear()
        Next
 End Sub
```

and call it like

```
CLEAR_TEXTBOXES(Me)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have almost everything you need. You just need to pass a reference to the form for which you want to clear the textboxes.

But a little issue you might run into is that controls, can have child controls as well (e.g. a textbox in a groupbox).

These are not picked up in the `.Controls` collection so you need a recursive method:

```
Public Sub ClearTextBoxesFromAControl(ctl As Control)
    For Each MyControl As Control In ctl.Controls
        If TypeOf MyControl Is TextBox Then
            MyControl.Text = ""
        End If
        If MyControl.HasChildren Then ClearTextBoxesFromAControl(MyControl)
    Next
End Sub
```

As A form inherits from a control you just need to pass the form reference to the method like this:

```
ClearTextBoxesFromAControl(Me)
```

Extra credit: You could even create an extension method to a form to do this:

In a `Public` module:

```
<Extension()>
Public Sub ClearAllTextBoxes(ctl As Control)
    For Each MyControl As Control In ctl.Controls
        If TypeOf MyControl Is TextBox Then
            MyControl.Text = ""
        End If
        If MyControl.HasChildren Then ClearAllTextBoxes(MyControl)
    Next
End Sub
```

Then you can call it like this `Me.ClearAllTextBoxes`